# How to NOT rotate text if the parent container is rotated

Tags: html, css

I've rotated a piece of content (the red div) that contains some text, but in rotating the container, it also rotates the text. How can I only rotate the div but keep the text not rotated?

In the setup, the HTML may not be allowed to change, so it would be good if the solution could only contain CSS. Not sure how to separate the rotation here. Thanks for any help.

```css
a {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
}
a .main-link-text {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: #c0392b;
    left: 0;
    height: 30%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    padding: 25px;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #fff;
    transform: rotate(5deg);
}
img { width: 100% }
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <span>
    <img src="https://www.safaribookings.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/What-todo-Encounter-Elephant-BW_1200px.jpg" alt="image-rawpixel-761473-unsplash.png">
  </span>
  <span class="main-link-text">
    Text to NOT rotate
  </span>
</a>
```

Comment: The text is inside the `span` being rotated. Why wouldn't it rotate as well? Try placing the text outside of the `span`.

Comment: in your styles you are rotating the `span`. and you are confused why it is rotating?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No html change:

```css
a {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
}
a .main-link-text {
    min-width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    padding: 25px;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 10;
}
a::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #c0392b;
    transform: rotate(5DEG);
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    z-index: 5;
}
img { width: 100% }
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <span>
    <img src="https://www.safaribookings.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/What-todo-Encounter-Elephant-BW_1200px.jpg" alt="image-rawpixel-761473-unsplash.png">
  </span>
  <span class="main-link-text">
    Text to NOT rotate
  </span>
</a>
```

A workaround can be:

```css
a {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
}
a .main-link-text {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: #c0392b;
    left: 0;
    height: 30%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    padding: 25px;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #fff;
    transform: rotate(5deg);
}
a .main-link-text-back {
    transform: rotate(-5deg);
}
img { width: 100% }
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <span>
    <img src="https://www.safaribookings.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/What-todo-Encounter-Elephant-BW_1200px.jpg" alt="image-rawpixel-761473-unsplash.png">
  </span>
  <span class="main-link-text">
    <span class="main-link-text-back">Text to NOT rotate</span>
  </span>
</a>
```

And actually I don't think if it's possible to rotate only the container without the content. Content always depends on the container properties...

Comment: Not really much of a workaround. It's just reversing the original transform on the text. Makes it redundant for no reason. The question also states that the HTML cannot be changed.

Comment: @Nick Yes and no. Technically you can solve it to immitate text in span, but it's not a too proper way. You can use div instead of span, but usually it's not a valid scenario by validators. So normally you can't move out the text from the span, if you want to do it in the proper way. Another way to do this with before/after, but it can be difficult, however it can be cleaner for somebody.